# Does "LG G Watch" has support for Bluetooth Classic

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, wear-os

I just saw the "LG G watch" in action.

Once we plugged the watch on the charger it turned on and then the steps were as follows:

1) Install the android wear app from the playstore on the smartphone

2) Scan for smart-watches from the smart-phone

3) Choose the "LG G watch" to pair with it

4) On the smart-watch it will ask you to confirm the pairing process

5) It starts downloading data from the smart-phone to the smart-watch

6) Once the downloading procedure is finished it starts installing apps on the smart-watch

7) All set and go

The procedure from step 5-7 took approximately 7-10 minutes.

In the android developers [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/assets.html) it says:

**Note: Although the size of data items are limited to 100KB, assets can be as large as desired. However, transferring large assets affect the user experience in many cases, so test your apps to ensure that they perform well if you're transferring large assets.**

Based on that i could say (but i am not sure) that it does not support Bluetooth Classic as i know that Bluetooth Classic can send much more than 100Kb

The way i see it, is that it could have Bluetooth Classic to transfer large amounts of data (installing apps, video, audio etc.). but if Bluetooth Classic was always turned on then the battery would not last much. On the other hand it could have Bluetooth Classic and the smart-watch could automatically enable and disable Bluetooth Classic whenever it needed to use it, in this way it would save battery consumption

I know that the smart-watch has Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE), but was the downloading of data from step 5 done through BLE or through Bluetooth Classic? Does the watch have Bluetooth Classic?

Answer (score 3):

g watch doesn't support BLE...so Bluetooth classic is all it's using. I've had one for over a month and have no reason to believe it supports BLE.

Answer (score 2):

When sending data between phones and Android Wear devices, it is all done through the data APIs provided by Android Wear. The implementation specific details are not visible to the programmer or the user, and may vary between different watches. The programmer is not able to control the existing connection, or make new connections to the phone. You should follow the guidelines in the Android Wear documentation http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/assets.html to ensure that your application will work on all watches available on the market.

Comment: So, if I'm understanding you right, than it's not possible to create a new/generic bluetooth connection to a different device than the paired smartphone. Let's say I want to search Bluetooth devices through my watch and connect with my notebook, which will receive data packets?

What I tried so far is that I am able to list all visible bluetooth devices but when trying to establish a connection the app on the smartwatch crashes. I couldn't figure out the exact meaning of the exception yet...